# I have a comment model, what to use in my views? @comment, :comment or comment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a comment model, I've seen examples of using `@comment, :comment, comment` to reference the object in MVC. how do I know which is which? Is there a distinction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `@comment` refers to an instance variable that a Rails controller makes available to a view. This is the most common usage
- `:comment` is a Ruby symbol and is used when the *name* of a model is required. You'll typically see this with the [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001604) helper and other view helpers that Rails provides
- `comment` is a local variable. You'll commonly see this in Rails when a view template uses a [partial template](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) (just called a partial). The parent view template passes one or more of its instance variables into the partial so that the partial has access to it/them, something like:

  `<%= render :partial => 'comment', :locals => { :comment => @comment } %>`

—In this example the comment partial (`comment.html.erb`) has access to the `@comment` instance variable via the `comment` local variable, so it can do things like `comment.author` etc.

Comment: Apologies, John. I felt it needed a little bit more explanation.

Comment: This is amazing, this should be explained more on ruby tutorials and books. Now my rails world is getting smaller towards mastery. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the context.

The first one, `@comment` is usually used (as John Topley similarly explained) for setting up a variable to be passed down the request chain to your views, helpers and partials that are rendered from that action.

If you're using it in a `form_for` you would reference the `@comment` object you most likely set up in the controller:

```
<% form_for @comment do |f| %>
```

If you're passing a comment object as a local to a partial you could specify it as a symbol (as John Topley said):

```
<%= render :partial => "info", :locals => { :comment => @comment }
```

And if you were using it as a local variable you may be rendering a collection of comments:

```
<%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
```

Passing the `comments` collection to partial will introspect upon the first object in here and determine it is of the `Comment` class and therefore will try to render the *comments/_comment.html.erb* partial for each of the items in the collection (regardless of what type the others are, this is a gotcha), making them each available as `comment` inside it.

Comment: Thank you! now I have explicit distinctions and understanding!